# Webpack is not always restarted after running an office add-in

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, office-js, office-addins

When I'm testing / debugging an Office Add-in for the first time, webpack is executed and the add-in runs successfully. However, when I stop the add-in and restart it, webpack does not always restart. If webpack does not start, the add-in fails. It seems like if I wait a bit of time, and then rerun the add-in, webpack starts again.

Is there anything I can do when running the add-in to ensure that webpack always runs when I start the add-in? Am I supposed to be terminating the add-in a certain way so that webpack always restarts immediately when I rerun the addin?

I typically just use something like `npm run start` on the add-on project. I would expect webpack to run every time so that the add-in does not fail. But that is not what I am seeing.

Comment: What is the webpack config? What's the underlying command used to run the watcher?

Answer (score 0):

It does matter how you stop the webpack server. You should always run `npm stop` to do this. This will also typically close the Office application. If it doesn't, close it.

Occasionally, the webpack server will appear to close when you run `npm stop` but is actually still running. If you suspect this, open task manager in Windows, find the Node process for the webpack server, and **End Task** on it.

Comment: After some further investigation, this seems to be an issue with the Node.js JavaScript Runtime. This is the process that the webpack subprocess runs under. It looks like webpack is not being run because the Node.js JavaScript Runtime is not being run. This is likely happening because the process is still terminating in the background. When this process is occurring, it is not visible in the task manager.